# Expectation of discrete random variable $X$ with $\mathbb{P}[X=n]=\frac{C}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

Consider a discrete random variable taking only positive integers $n >5$ as values with $\mathbb{P}[X=n]=\frac{C}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$.

$$E(X)=\sum_{x=5}^{\infty}x \cdot P[X=x]\\=\sum_{x=5}^{\infty}x \cdot\dfrac{C}{x(x+1)(x+2)}\\ =\sum_{x=5}^{\infty}\dfrac{C}{(x+1)(x+2)}.$$

The series converges, but what is its sum?

Comment: If $n \gt 5$, should you start the sum at $x=6$?

Comment: Henry, >=, I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use partial fraction expansion: $\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)} = \frac{1}{k+1} -\frac{1}{k+2}$, you get a telescoping sum. Can you handle from here?

Comment: So, for any k >= 5 we have Sum(k) = 1/6 - 1/(k+2), and Sum(k \to \infty) = 1/6. But I have a constant in the numerator, and the answer C/6 is not a particular number. It's strange.

Comment: $C$ is used for normalization. You can find it by setting $1=\sum_{k=5}^{\infty}P(X=k)$ and then solving for $C$

Comment: Could you explain this moment in more detail, please?

Comment: Basically you need to solve $1=\sum_{k=5}^{\infty}\frac{C}{k(k+1)(k+2)}$ for $C$, which is done is pretty much the same way - by expanding in partial fractions.